# Using the $q service in AngularJS to handle promises

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise

I have a service which needs to store some settings data in a DB and at the same time maintain a reference to that in the user's`localStorage` (we want two users logged in to the same account to be able to view them differently). This method looks for an existing `previewSession` in the `localStorage` and if not found, creates one and generates a unique URL.

As you can see at the beginning, I'm using the `$q` service to return a promise and then resolving that promise as and when all operations have finished. There is one use of the `$http` service and the save call is on a `$resource` object.

Is this a proper way to handle such a use-case, or could I have done it better?

To summarize the requirements:

1. Method gets called with a settings parameter
2. Method must always return a URL (unless an error occurs on the db level or some such thing)

```
var PREVIEW_SESSION_KEY_BASE = '<a constant string>';    
function getPreviewSessionUrl(settings) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/' + appCode + '/reservedDomain',
            function(appResponse) {
                $localForage
                    .getItem(PREVIEW_SESSION_KEY_BASE + themeId)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                            deferred.resolve(appResponse + '?<a query key>=' + data);
                        } else {
                            previewSessionResource.save(
                                {},
                                {
                                    settings: settings
                                },
                                function(previewResponse) {
                                    $localForage
                                        .setItem(PREVIEW_SESSION_KEY_BASE + themeId, previewResponse)
                                        .then(function(data) {
                                            deferred.resolve(appResponse + '?<a query key>=' + data);
                                        });
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    deferred.reject(error);
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    });
            },
            function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Not much of a review, but simply the fact that you have a pyramid of doom style code, implies that you're using promises wrong.

Comment: True. I completely disregarded chaining of the `then` calls. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that could have been better;

- This:

  ```
          },    
          function(error) {
              deferred.reject(error);
          }
      );
  ```

  could simply be

  ```
          }, deferred.reject );
  ```

  `reject` is a function that takes `error` as a parameter after all..
- I would have externalized the `previewSessionResource.save(`call, it makes the reading too hard. You only capture `settings` and `appResponse` which you would then provide as parameters.
- If you control the signature of `previewSessionResource.save`, then I would simply request for `settings` as an object instead of requesting for `{ settings: settings }` to keep it simple, it does not make sense to wrap a single data point into an object.
- I am also idly wondering if `previewSessionResource.save` should not be responsible for calling `$localForage.setItem()`, would you ever call `previewSessionResource.save` without calling `$localForage.setItem()`?

On the whole, I think this is okay, it just needs some rejiggering to read better.

Comment: Thanks @konijn! Yeah, readability is the main issue here. I'll refactor the code, accordingly.